# advanceddatagriditemrenderer formatting based on column information

Tags: flash, apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I need to be able to change the formatting of rows and cells based on whether the information being displayed has been flagged as in violation of business rules. I've made a custom advanceddatagriditemrenderer and gotten it to do the formatting I want, but I can't figure out any way to reference the data being displayed or the column being displayed in (I need both for what I'm doing) within the renderer.

I've tried implementin gIDropInListItemRenderer but data and listData are still both null.

Answer (score 1):

can you give some example code?

in AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer, you can get the data and listData in validateProperties function.

```
override public function validateProperties():void
    {
        super.validateProperties();

        if (listData)
        {
            var dg:AdvancedDataGrid = AdvancedDataGrid(listData.owner);
            var column:AdvancedDataGridColumn = dg.columns[listData.columnIndex];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about passing a reference to the column object while creating the renderer factory.

```
var columnFooRendererFactory:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(ColumnFooRenderer);
columnFooRendererFactory.properties = { parentColumn: fooColumn };
fooColumn.itemRenderer = columnFooRendererFactory;
```

Comment: I think he trying to implement DropInListItemRenderer type instead external itemRenderer

Comment: I ended up extending Canvas and that worked when I implemented DropInListItemRenderer. Thanks!